# write spark DF to HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF which has ~500K records:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

I am trying to write the DF to a HDFS folder:

```
someDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("hdfs/path/my_folder")
```

I am not getting any errors, but the folder has only empty files.

Any suggestions on the issue?

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `"hdfs/path/my_folder"` is not a HDFS URL. It should look something like `"hdfs://<host>:<port>/path/my_folder"`

Comment: 1st thing to fix, correct the hdfs path as @SteveC mentioned 2nd thing are you sure that someDF contains any data?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis I have the path in the correct format as mentioned. I just did not give the full path here. Also I checked the count for the DF, it is ~500K records as expected.

Comment: @SteveC I have the path in the correct format as mentioned. I just did not give the full path here. Also I checked the count for the DF, it is ~500K records as expected.